# Create automatic page breaks in textarea (redactor)

Tags: javascript, html, css, redactor

I currently using redactor. The documents being created on my site are intended for eventual printing, so I want the user to see the page breaks as they edit. I can easily appended an absolute positioned div which will show the user where the page breaks will be, but because they are absolute positioned, I have not found a way to make the text a user is typing actual break around the page break. For example, the page break currently would just sit on top of an image instead of forcing the image to start below it.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KwxXjm

currently this is what I am doing, after I create the redactor instance:

The Javascript

```
$('.redactor-editor').append("<div class='page-break1'></div>");
```

The css

```
.redactor-editor .page-break1{
    page-break-after: always;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1420px;
    height: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    background-color: red;
}

.redactor-editor{
    position: relative;
}
```

Definitely aware that absolute css may not be the way to go, I'm just not sure what is. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good pluging http://ckeditor.com/ to TextArea good editor with defirent mode and level details need the user